# How to have multiple H1 tags defined in CSS for a theme

Tags: theme, css

I am trying to override my current theme's H1 tag on product view only.

Current CSS

**styles.css**

```
.product-view
h1            {  background: url("../images/image.jpg") repeat scroll 50% 0 transparent;
border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: normal;
height: 28px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-top: 6px; }
```

I have added a separate class with a unique H1 to override the above:

```
.product-name-new h1 { font-size:16px; color:#73472e; font-weight:bold; width:350px;}
```

I cannot seem to override the CSS, I have also tried entering the CSS directly in my view.phtml file:

**view.phtml**

```
<h1><style=font-size:16px; color:#73472e; font-weight:bold; width:350px;><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></style></h1>
```

As soon as I use the < h1> tag, it uses the original code and not the code I would like to use to override my products name.

How can I correctly implement a separate H1 tag on the product view that will not affect the rest of the theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of problems:

**There is no "style" tag in HTML:**

`<h1><style=font-size:16px; color:#73472e; font-weight:bold; width:350px;><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></style></h1>`

Instead, remove the `<style>` and its' ending tag, leaving:

```
<h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
```

**Your CSS assumes that there is a parent class named .product-name-new**

This means that it will ONLY style markup organized as such:

```
<div class="product-name-new">
    <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?></h1>
</div>
```

**If that's not what you meant to do**, instead you can modify both the css rule and the h1 markup by giving it a class. E.g.:

**Markup:**

```
<h1 class="product-name-new"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?></h1>
```

**CSS:**

```
h1.product-name-new {
    background: url("../images/image.jpg") repeat scroll 50% 0 transparent;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 28px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 6px;
}
```

HTH, Cheers.

Comment: To clarify: the code I posted for view.phtml was an example of what I tried to see if I could override the default CSS. 

Your example has helped me understand what I was doing wrong and I was able to correctly resolve my issue. Thank you!